# Why does TeX Live's pdflatex produce smaller PDFs than MiKTeX's pdflatex?

Tags: pdf, texlive, miktex, file-size

When building my master thesis, I've found that the size of the produced PDF differs if I use Tex Live on Ubuntu compared to MiKTeX on Windows; for the latter, the size is about 50% greater (from about 600KB to some 900KB).

I'm just curious why this might be. I mean, the *look* and *layout* is the same (as far as I can tell, at least). So where do these extra 300KB come from?

### UPDATE

Okay, so on the MikTeX I got `pdfTeX 2.9.4225 (1.40.12)`, and on TeXLive I got `pdfTex 2.3-1.40.12`. The two versions are available below:

[LiveTeX version](http://web.ict.kth.se/~ghb/report_texlive_version.pdf)

[MikTeX version](http://web.ict.kth.se/~ghb/report_miktex_version.pdf)

Comment: Do you use different versions of pdftex? What happens if you set the `\pdfcompresslevel` to the same (known) value?

Comment: @Marco: Don't know. Will check that as soon as I get home from work today.

Comment: If you published both versions of PDF, others could check the contents of the PDF for the important differences. There can be multiple reasons: PDF compression, font versions, verbosity, ...

Comment: @tohecz: Done..

Comment: The TeXlive version has compressed object streams. That indicates that MikTeX and TeXlive have different settings for `\pdfobjcompresslevel`.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: Ah, but why wouldn't one want to have the highest setting by default? Is it a non-lossless compression? Are older viewers not capable of decompressing higher compression levels? Btw, you should give that comment as an answer instead. =)

Comment: By the way: I tried to convert both PDFs to low-res (96dpi) bitmaps, and they are all the same except for pages 142 and 143: **they differ in line-breaking of the bibliography entries [1], [7], [11], [12], always in the URLs**. Seems that the two compilers use different TFM's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TeXlive version has compressed object streams. That indicates that MikTeX and TeXlive have different settings for `\pdfobjcompresslevel`. compressed object streams is a lossless compression method, where not just a single object is compressed, but a range of objects. This leads to smaller sizes. Why one distribution would set it as a default and the other one not, is beyond my knowledge. And without MikTeX installation to verify, I can only assume that they have different defaults.

When uncompressed, they still don't have the same size:

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable report_texlive_version.pdf texlive.pdf

4905818 miktex.pdf
4868473 texlive.pdf
```

That's still about 1% difference.

Comment: In my humble opinion, 1%-difference is not a real difference, it can be due to double procession that can add some meta-data or similar stuff...